# Desenvolvimento Ionic para ios em um ambiente windows ou linux é possível?

Tags: ios, ionic

Queria saber se existe alguma maneira de criar aplicações para iOS quando o nosso sistema operacional é windows ou linux.

Segundo essa [informação do cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html), teríamos que ter um sistema operacional OS-X.

Existe algum workaround?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é possível pois é necessário recursos do MacOS e XCode tal como o ambiente iOS SDK para compilar aplicativos iOS.

As opções mais próximas seriam:

- **Cloud**

  São serviços de compilação de apps nas nuvens.
  Nesse caso, qualquer sistema operacional pode ser usado pois o trabalho de compilação é determinado pelos computadores da empresa que fornece o serviço.
  Aqui você "perde" a privacidade e até segurança do projeto, pois está dando de "bandeja" os códigos para um terceiro. Mas não é uma opção ruim. Cada um deve calcular os seus próprios riscos. Contudo, isso é outro assunto não pertinente ao que pergunta.
- **Virtualização**

  Instalar o MacOS por meio de ambiente virtualizado (VirtualBox, VMWare, etc).

  É normalmente uma tarefa complicada e dificilmente terá um resultado satisfatório. Na maioria das vezes não compensa mas é o mais simples e próximo do que necessita.
- **Hackintosh**

  Fazer modificações em configurações de hardware de um PC para poder instalar um MacOS. Nesse caso deixa de ser Windows ou Linux, o que fugiria do seu objetivo. A única "vantagem" é não precisar comprar um Mac.

  É também uma tarefa muito complicada e na maioria das vezes é ineficaz. Além disso é considerado crime pois é usado versões piratas do MacOS. Obviamente que não deve fazer isso num ambiente corporativo.

Opinião pessoal, não se iluda muito com gambiarras. A princípio podem trazer algum resultado (bem porco), mas não conseguirá manter de forma segura e estável. *<sub>referente a hachintosh e virtualização</sub>

O "segredo" dessas plataformas "híbridas" de desenvolvimento é na verdade uma grande gambiarra. É tudo baseado em HTML/JavaScript que rodam sob uma classe "webView" do sistema operacional alvo (Android / iOS).

Basicamente abre-se uma janela do browser dentro do app. Resumindo grosseiramente, o app final é apenas um "buraco" na tela que chama o browser padrão do sistema operacional e captura eventos JavaScript. Esses eventos JavaScript são capturados pelos recursos nativos do dispositivo, por isso, é possível o acesso a determinados recursos nativos.

Comment: Daniel, tenho vários amigos que fazem apps em phonegap, e pergunto-lhes se vêm alguma diferença entre essas apps e as apps nativas a 100%, e eles dizem que não. O que acha? Parece ter experiencia no assunto daí a minha pergunta, acha que é uma má ideia porquê mais precisamente?

Comment: Depende muito do que o app necessita. Para coisas simples que pode resolver com HTML/JavaScript eu também prefiro escrever o app em HTML pois não faz diferença. A difrença maior é que torna o desenvolvimento 1000% mais simples. Eu particularmente não uso ferramentas como phonegap pois desenvolvi moldes semi-prontos e apenas replico os apps. Na hora de compilar, se é para iOS trabalho com o Mac. Se for para Android vou no Windows ou dependendo do caso faço tudo no Mac. Para apps mais complexos vc vai perceber que nem tudo se resolve com HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: Entendo, obrigado pelo esclarecimento Daniel

Comment: Daniel, valeu pela informação. Eu já tinha imaginado isso, que os apps desenvolvidos com essas ferramentas eram apenas uma espécie de browser do celular.  Então na prática teríamos que ter 2 computadores para desenvolvimento? Um iOS e outro windows? O que vc considera coisas não simples. Quais exemplos não seriam resolvidos com ionic ou phonegap? Uma pergunta um mac poderia desenvolver para Android e Windows?

Comment: No Intel XDK vc consegue desenvolver para android, ios e windows phone com html/css, da até para gerar o arquivo .ipa e instalar no seu iphone, só vai precisar de um mac para mandar o aplicativo para loja. Eu faço utilizando Ionic, em androids mais antigos fica bem lento, agora em androids, iphones e windows phones mais novos fica show, tem muitos plugins para poder usar os recursos nativos do celular, mas é claro, nativo fica sempre melhor, hibrido é mais rápido na hora do desenvolvimento, nativo demora mais porém fica com um resultado final bem melhor.