# Posso utilizar um iPhone para testar um app Xamarin?

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin, xamarin-forms, emulador

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver com Xamarin (Utilizando o VS 2015 e Windows). Para testar o app no Android é tranquilo, utilizo o Genymotion. E no IOS? Como posso testar? Apenas com um iPhone físico ? Ou existe um emulador de IOS?

Comment: Essa resposta server para sua dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164307/desenvolvimento-ionic-para-ios-em-um-ambiente-windows-ou-linux-%C3%A9-poss%C3%ADvel

Comment: Emulador iOS somente no macOS, através do Xcode, infelizmente. Legalmente falando, não existem outros recursos: ou você tem um Mac, ou paga pra usar o de alguém. Extra-oficialmente existem alguns "hacks"...

Comment: Esse link pode ajudar você com algumas coisas importantes... https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um emulador de iOS para desenvolvimento, pelo menos não no Windows. Fazer isso violaria a licença imposto pela Apple.

No novo Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, ou seja, o bem caro, tem uma forma de [testar remotamente com um simulador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ios-simulator/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Você pode [testar em MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html) ou um [serviço que ofereça o emulador remotamente](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/introduction-to-test-cloud/). O mesmo vale pra publicação.

Existem [emuladores do *device*](https://www.technonutty.com/2015/09/ios-simulator-windows-emulators-for-ios.html), mas eu tenho a impressão que isto quebra a licença de uso do iOS porque [nem em VM pode rodá-lo se o hardware não for Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139924/66961). Mais uma [coletânea](http://www.techgyd.com/best-ios-emulator-for-windows/23093/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar testes através do "simulador" do iphone será necessário possuir um Mac ou um serviço de aluguel de Mac como por exemplo MacInCloud para realizar a compilação de seu aplicativo, utilizando o Xamarin Mac Agent no visual Studio.

Configuração do Xamarin Mac Agent
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/

Recentemente a Microsoft anunciou o Xamarin Live Player, que possibilita você realizar testes no seu celular Android ou iOS, através deste aplicativo, é uma boa solução caso não tenha um Mac para desenvolvimento, lembrando que mesmo utilizando esse produto, você necessitará de um MAc para realizar a compilação e publicação na AppStore.

Maiores informações:
https://www.xamarin.com/live

O Xamarin Live Player possui várias limitações, portanto, aplicações complexas e com recursos avançados podem não funcionar muito bem.

Recomendo a utilização deste recurso para aplicações simples no momento, pois, acredito que irão melhorar essa solução com o tempo.

Você tem essas opções hoje, veja qual se adapta a seu cenário.

Answer (score 2):

> Posso utilizar um iPhone para testar um app Xamarin?

Sim, você pode utilizar um dispositivo iPhone conectado via cabo para testar seu projeto diretamente

> Ou existe um emulador de IOS?

Não existe emulador *iOS* para Windows ou Linux

### [Xamarin Hot Restart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart)

Como dito antes, se você tiver um iPhone poderá testar com o Xamarin no Windows, note que **Visual Studio 2015** não suporta isso, será necessário:

- Visual Studio 2019 versão 16.5
- iTunes (64-bit) instalado
- Conta Apple Developer e ter pago a [inscrição no programa Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)
- Ter um iPhone (64-bit)

Antes de tudo `Xamarin Hot Restart` é desabilitado por padrão, para habilitar vá em: <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Environment</kbd> > <kbd>Preview Features</kbd> > <kbd>Enable Xamarin Hot Restart</kbd> (eu não sei o caminho em Português, sinta-se livre parar [editar](/posts/485199/edit) a resposta)

### Limitações:

- Apenas aplicativos iOS criados com `Xamarin.Forms` e dispositivos iOS são atualmente suportados
- Apenas dispositivos iOS de 64 bits são suportados. A partir do "iOS 11", a Apple não permite mais a execução de aplicativos iOS na arquitetura de 32 bits (dispositivos anteriores ao "iPhone 5s")
- Os arquivos `Storyboard` e `XIB` não são suportados e o aplicativo pode travar se tentar carregá-los durante a execução. Use o símbolo de pré-processador "HOTRESTART" para impedir a execução deste código
- Bibliotecas e estruturas estáticas "iOS" não são suportadas e você pode ver erros de tempo de execução ou travamentos se seu aplicativo tentar carregá-los. Use o símbolo de pré-processador `HOTRESTART` para impedir a execução deste código. Bibliotecas iOS dinâmicas são suportadas
- Você não pode usar o "Xamarin Hot Restart" para criar pacotes de aplicativos para publicação. Você ainda precisará de uma máquina Mac para fazer uma compilação completa, assinatura e implantação de seu aplicativo para **produção**, ou seja o foco aqui é somente desenvolvimento e testes
- Catálogos de ativos não são suportados atualmente. Ao usar "Xamarin Hot Restart", seu aplicativo mostrará o ícone padrão e a tela de inicialização para aplicativos Xamarin. Quando emparelhado com um Mac ou desenvolvendo em um Mac, seus Catálogos de ativos funcionarão

Apesar das limitações é mais fácil que rodar um VM (hackintosh) e provavelmente o custo-benefício e a depuração em tempo real serão muito mais fáceis, claro que na hora de publicar vai precisar de um computador Mac ou contratar um serviço de terceiros

> Como a [**Apple afirmou**](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/), que a partir de março de 2019 todos os aplicativos e atualizações enviados à App Store devem ter sido desenvolvidos com o iOS **12.1 SDK** ou posterior, incluído no **Xcode 10.1** ou posterior. Os aplicativos também devem ser compatíveis com os tamanhos de tela iPhone XS e 12,9 para iPad Pro.

### Configurando

1. Certifique-se de que o projeto iOS esteja definido como o projeto de inicialização e a configuração de construção esteja definida como <kbd>Debug|iPhone</kbd>
2. Se este for um projeto existente, vá para <kbd>Build</kbd> > <kbd>Configuration Manager...</kbd> e certifique-se de que Deploy está habilitado para o projeto iOS

   [image: visual studio local device iOS]
3. Conecte um dispositivo iOS à sua computador. Se um dispositivo já estiver conectado, desconecte e reconecte-o. O nome do dispositivo aparecerá no assistente assim que for detectado. Clique em <kbd>Next</kbd>
4. Insira as credenciais da sua **conta de desenvolvedor** da Apple e clique em <kbd>Next</kbd>
5. Selecione uma "team" usando o menu suspenso para habilitar o [**automatic provisioning**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows) no projeto. Clique em <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
6. Se o dispositivo não aparecer conecte de novo, então deverá aparecer conectado no menu suspenso de destino de depuração. Para depurar seu aplicativo, selecione seu dispositivo na lista suspensa e clique no botão **Run**
7. Para reiniciar pode usar o atalho Ctrl+Shift+F5 ou clicar em Restart:

   [image: Reiniciar o Xamarin Hot Restart]